# Set router in ListItem button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, material-design

I have below set of `ListItem` inside `List`. Now on click event, i want it to route to new react component. How to do it?

```
<List>
    <ListItem button key= "Account">
        <ListItemIcon>{<MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary= "Account" />
    </ListItem>

    <ListItem button key= "Student">
        <ListItemIcon>{<InboxIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary= "Student" />
    </ListItem>
</List>
```

Answer (score 1):

> on click event, i want it to route to new react component

You can use the `history` prop. Like this:

```
onClick={ () => this.props.history.push("/your-page") }
```

You need a corresponding `Route`:

```
<Route path="/your-page" component={YourComponent} />
```

Comment: I am using a functional component `export default function MenuDrawer` like this. Will it work in this case?

Comment: Then you don't have `this`. So try `props.history.push("/your-page")`. Don't forget to import props in your function signature. Like this: `function MenuDrawer(props) {//your code }` @Lara

Comment: On click event i am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`, why is this coming?

Comment: @Lara You might need to wrap `MenuDrawer` with `withRouter`. Like this: `export default function withRouter(MenuDrawer)`. Don't forget to import `withRouter` from `react-router-dom`.

Comment: Thanks, could you please give me a small example, i am very new to react and not able to understand it quiet well, a small example will be a good start for me..thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can make ue of [`Link`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md) from `react-router-dom`,

```
<List>
  <Link to="/account">
    <ListItem button key= "Account">
      <ListItemIcon>{<MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary= "Account" />
    </ListItem>
  </Link>

  <Link to="/student">
    <ListItem button key= "Student">
      <ListItemIcon>{<InboxIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary= "Student" />
    </ListItem>
  </Link>
</List>
```

Of course you need `Route` to handle them.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-srshwv)

You can learn more about Routing [here](https://blog.pshrmn.com/simple-react-router-v4-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks so much Ravi, could you please help me with `Route` as well, i am very new and need a starting point..Kindly help or guide me to a link.Thanks

Comment: @Lara, Check the Demo, I have tried to create a simple Demo with Route's.

Comment: @Lara, Have you checked the Demo? It is helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Link from react-router-dom

```
<List component="nav">
      {orders.map(item =>
           <ListItem key={item.key} component={Link} button to={'/car/add/' + item.key} >
               <ListItemText primary={item.title} />
          </ListItem>
       )}
</List>
```

Comment: cleanest answer so far